# Xcode 4 and CoreData: How to drop a table of an entity

Tags: xcode, core-data

I really dont know how to delete a table of an entity within CoreData. I can only see the Button "Add Entity" but apparently there is no Button "Remove Entity" or anything like that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just highlight the entity and hit the delete button.